# understanding summation by parts

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_k )$ and $(b_k )$ be sequences in $C$ and let $s_n := \sum_{j=0}^n a_j $

Show that $\sum_{j=0}^n a_jb_j  = b_{n+1} s_n - \sum_{k=0}^n s_k (b_{k+1} − b_k ) $

solution goes as follows, 
$\sum_{k=0}^n s_k (b_{k+1} − b_k )= \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^k a_j (b_{k+1} − b_k ) = \color{red}{\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=j}^n} a_j (b_{k+1} − b_k )$

Can someone please explain how the summation limits in red are derived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last equality uses an identity that holds in general. Consider any sum
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^k x_j y_k &= \sum_{k=0}^n y_k \sum_{j=0}^k x_j \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n y_k \{ x_0 + x_1 + \dots x_k \} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \{ x_0 y_k + x_1 y_k + \dots x_k y_k \} \\
&= \{ x_0 y_0 \} \\
&+ \{ x_0 y_1 \} + \{ x_1 y_1 \} \\
&+ \{ x_0 y_2 \} + \{ x_1 y_2 \} + \{ x_2 y_2 \} \\
&+ \dots \\
&+ \{ x_0 y_n \} + \dots \dots \dots + \{ x_n y_n \}.
\end{align}
Now sum up the terms vertically to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^k x_j y_k &= x_0 \{ y_0 + \dots + y_n \} \\
&+ x_1 \{ y_1 + \dots + y_n \} \\
&+ \dots \\
&+ x_k \{ y_k + \dots + y_n \} \\
&+ \dots \\
&+ x_n \{ y_n \} \\
&= x_0 \sum_{k=0}^n y_k + x_1 \sum_{k=1}^n y_k + \dots + x_n \sum_{k=n}^n y_k \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^n x_j \sum_{k=j}^n y_k \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=j}^n x_j y_k
\end{align}
Set $x_j = a_j$ and $y_k = (b_{k+1} - b_k)$ to apply it to your case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.